# Add up the value of data[x] to data[x+1]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of data which I am working with now,containing a list of 'timestamp' versus 'quantity'. However, the timestamp in the list is not all in order (for example,timestamp[x] can be 140056 while timestamp[x+1] can be 560). I am not going to arrange them, but to add up the value of timestamp[x] to timestamp[x+1] when this happens.

ps:The arrangement of quantity needs to be in the same order as in the list when plotting.

I have been working with this using the following code, which timestamp is the name of the list which contain all the timestamp values:

```
for t in timestamp:
    previous = timestamp[t-1]
    increment = 0
    if previous > timestamp[t]:  
        increment = previous
    t += increment
    delta = datetime.timedelta(0, (t - startTimeStamp) / 1000);
    timeAtT = fileStartDate + (delta + startTime)
    print("time at t=" + str(t) + " is: " + str(timeAtT));
    previous = t
```

However it comes out with TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuples. May I know how to solve this, or any other ways of doing this task? Thanks!

Comment: `for t in timestamps` this iterates through the *items* in `timestamps` not the indices

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that timestamp is the name of list which contain all the timestamp values, and you can call out certain thing in the list using, for example, 'print (timestamp[4])', and it will give out the values. However, now what I want to do is to check through everything in the list.

Comment: Show us a snippet of the contents of `timestamp`

Comment: First, you should post the exact error message - most importantly, this will tell *which* access to timestamp is broken. Second, there seem to be several things wrong. `for t in timestamp` will make `t` represent timestamps (e.g. `1467374702.602727`), not indices (e.g. `16`); doing `timestamp[t]` or `timestamp[t-1]` should already fail, unless you list is long and your timestamps small integers. If it doesn't fail, its result is not sensible. `startTimeStamp` and `startTime` seem strangely related. You're also not modifying the list, just printing. Etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're treating `t` as if it is an *index* of the list. In your case, `t` holds the actual values of the list, so constructions like `timestamp[t]` are not valid. You either want:

```
for t in range(len(timestamp)):
```

Or if you want both an index and the value:

```
for (t, value) in enumerate(timestamp):
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `for the in timestamp` you are making `t` take on the value of each item in timestamp. But then you try to use `t` as an index to make `previous`. To do this, try:

```
for i, t, in enumerate(timestamp):
    previous = timestamp[i]
    current = t
```

Also when you get TypeErrors like this make sure you try printing out the intermediate steps, so you can see exactly what is going wrong.